# How to know will the selected azure hosting plan will work for my web app hosting

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I want to host 1 web app in windows OS with SQL server database. I have selected b1 instance and selected S0 database. I have selected app service and storage is these 2 things are enough to host a app? can we run this app for 24 hrs?

app is smart city dashboard app. **concurrent** users will be  max of **10**. 10 department person may watch the app concurrently the app. this app is not for public user. this will be for the office admin purpose to monitor city utilities like transformer temperature, intrusion detection. some of the web pages have page refresh of 30 seconds. so the app will refresh every 30 seconds and it will check the database in every 30 seconds.

app is already developed in asp.net mvc with sql server database with entity framework.

```
APP SERVICE PLAN B1 
CORES   1   
RAM     1.75 GB
STORAGE 10 GB


database - single database
Purchase Model - DTU
Service Tier- General Purpose

PLAN    S0
DTUS    10
INCLUDED STORAGE 250GB
MAX STORAGE      250 GB
```

my queries

according to selected plan there is 10 gb space. so is that space for app deployment.or it is for .net framework installation and sql server management studio installation.

there is mentioned, only 10 DTU in database. can i fetch data from database any number of times or 10 times only i can fetch data.

Comment: As it stands now, the question is really broad. You would need to provide more details about your app. For example, how many concurrent users etc. Please edit your question and include more details.

Answer (score 0):

The size is the size of **everything** your Web app will use not the underline infrastructure.

In regards to DTU, there are many option for SQL you can choose from depending on your needs.  Rather than a single database you can use elastic pool or managed instances.

Below is **a link to a DTU page**, there are links on that page to other options, you have review an decide which option is suitable for your application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tiers-dtu

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the database you can simulate the intended workload with the current application developed with .Net Framework and SQL Server during that simulation you can collect performance counters that can be used by [Azure DTU Calculator](http://dtucalculator.azurewebsites.net/) to estimate the appropiate number of DTUs (service level) that you need for your database,